# Passport Local Mongoose Error: No Username Was Given

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I have an express app and I'm trying to add users with passport local mongoose, but whenever I try to create a user, I get an error saying `MissingUsernameError: No username was given`.

Here's the relevant code:

User Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

register.ejs:

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="two fields">
    <div class="field">
      <input type="text" name="email" value="<%= email %>">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
var mongoose       = require('mongoose'),
passport           = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy      = require('passport-local'),
User               = require('./models/user'),


app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'very secret words',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

//New user creation
app.post('/newuser', function(req, res){
  var newUser = new User({username: req.body.email});
  console.log(newUser);
  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      console.log('error registering user');
      console.log(err);
      return res.send('oops');
    }
    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function(){
      res.redirect('/matches');
    });
  }); 
});
```

can anyone see what I'm missing? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure to give `body-parser` code before all the routes

`app.use(express.bodyParser());`

After that check that you have given both fields like `username` and `password` in form during request since `passport.authenticate('local')` check these values and if anyone is mismatched then it won't gonna work.

Refer the Passport.js doc for more details

http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password

**Update**

```
var User = require('./models/user');

// CHANGE: USE "createStrategy" INSTEAD OF "authenticate"
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

> The reason for this functionality is that when using the usernameField option to specify an alternative usernameField name, for example "email" passport-local would still expect your frontend login form to contain an input field with name `"username" instead of email`. This can be configured for passport-local but this is double the work. So we got this shortcut implemented.

See the [https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#options)

Comment: on your userSchema where you initially defined your user model, you can modify your strategy to use an alternative login field: userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: 'email' });

Answer (score 1):

OK so I found the solution to my problem–in case anyone else gets here with the same issue.

I had `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the signup form. Removing this fixes the problem. I don't understand why though, so if anyone can shed some light on that I'd be very grateful.

Also, I can see another problem on the horizon; I want this form to not only register the user's username and password, but also to add info about them to the database, including photos. As far as I understand, if I want to upload files from a form I need `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Does anyone know a solution for this? (Should this be a separate question?)

Comment: I don't have any enctype= multipart/form-data and ahappens the same to me :(

Comment: If you're still having trouble post some code and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: I'm good! just solved right now thanx @Runny Yolk, I REALLY appreciate your help :D

It was calling to config.secrekey instea of config.secret and no err was thrown :S

Answer (score 0):

change the input "name" attribute value from name="email"
to name="username"
that could fix it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the body parser before your routes.

I had the same problem as I was missing

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Change your schema structure like this:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
})
```

and then also change your name attributes in `<form>` tag:

```html
<input name="username" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema from a normal javascript object to a new "mongoose.Schema()".

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String
});
```

And make sure body-parser is being used before using any variables specified inside the HTML body.
A good practice is to put it when we initialize app :

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));enter code here
```

It might help changing name in the HTML forms but in my case, it worked normally without changing any part in HTML or fields inside the schema

Answer (score 0):

while creating a new user does not require creating a variable newUser you can directly do this

```
//New user creation
app.post('/newuser', function(req, res){
  User.register({username: req.body.email}, req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      console.log('error registering user');
      console.log(err);
      return res.send('oops');
    }
    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function(){
      res.redirect('/matches');
    });
  }); 
});
```